# What's the best way to select() based on toolchain with bazel?

Tags: bazel

The documentation (https://docs.bazel.build/configurable-attributes.html) offers the following example, which sadly doesn't work:

```
cc_library(
    name = "my_lib",
    deps = select(
        {
            "//tools/cc_target_os:android": [":android_deps"],
            "//tools/cc_target_os:windows": [":windows_deps"],
        },
        no_match_error = "Please build with an Android or Windows toolchain",
    ),
)
```

Matchers such as "@platforms//os:macos" and "@platforms//os:windows" sadly only detect HOST platform but not TARGET platform. This breaks when cross-compiling on a different architecture.

I came up with an "android" matcher that works:

```
config_setting(
    name = "android",
    values = {"crosstool_top": "//external:android/crosstool"},
)
```

But cannot figure out a way to match windows, macos or linux TARGET toolchains.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are looking for platforms: https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/platforms.html and the `target_compatible_with` attribute on `cc_library`.

I would suggest you want something like:

```
cc_library(
    name = "my_lib_android",
    deps = [":android_deps"],
    target_compatible_with = [
        "@platforms//os:android",
    ],
)

cc_library(
    name = "my_lib_windows",
    deps = [":windows_deps"],
    target_compatible_with = [
        "@platforms//os:windows",
    ],
)
```

The user of my_lib would then have to depend on either my_lib_android or my_lib_windows as appropriate.

Comment: I think you might have misunderstood my question. I already something like that, and now I need to perform a select() to match the right library with the right crosstool.

The issue with "@platforms//os:windows" and "@platforms//os:macos" is that they match HOST platform but not TARGET platform. In other words, they work if you only build windows targets on windows and macos targets on macos but if you try cross-compiling, they break. I am setting up a linux server that builds all targets as a presubmit check, and "@platforms//os:macos" never matches even when building a macos_application().

Comment: Do they not match when in the target_compatible_with field? You probably have to define a platform to say that you are cross compiling for it to work though. Also you might need to switch to `--incompatible_enable_cc_toolchain_resolution` instead of `--crosstool_top` to get this all to work.

Comment: no such attribute 'target_compatible_with' in 'cc_library' rule

Comment: Here is an example that illustrates the issue: https://pastebin.com/ZKdZeNnF

Comment: What version of bazel are you using? https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/c-cpp.html#cc_library

Comment: I'm running bazel 3.7.0-homebrew which I believe is the latest and it's missing from 3.7.0 docs: https://docs.bazel.build/versions/3.7.0/be/c-cpp.html#cc_library